# Prevent form from being refreshing when submitted in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I have a `Reactjs` component in this component .I have a form inside the `form` i have a  `search field`..when the user hit `enter` my `component` reloads.I want to use |prevent default`so that my`component`not reloads when user hits`enter key`.How to use in my` code`

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import data from "./info.json";
    function App() {
      const [searchTerm, setSearch] = useState(null);
    
      return (
        <div>
           <form>
          <input
            type="text"
            id=""
            placeholder="Search"
            onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
          />
</form>
    
          {data
            .filter((data) => {
              if (searchTerm == null) {
                return data;
              } else if (
                data.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
              ) {
                return data;
              }
            })
            .map((data) => (
              <li>{data.name}</li>
            ))}
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an onSubmit event handler on the form ,

```
<form onSubmit={handleOnsubmit}> </form>
```

in your handleOnsubmit function perfrom event.preventDefault()

```
function handleOnsubmit(event) {

   event.preventDefault();
   // Do Whatever you want
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

**You will need to add `preventDefault()` to your form like so:**

Add `preventDefault()` to your `onSubmit` event of your form:

```
<form onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault()}>
  <input
    type="text"
    id=""
    placeholder="Search"
    onChange={e => {
      setSearch(e.target.value);
    }}
  />
</form>;
```

[image: Edit polished-hill-bg7dn]

Answer (score 1):

ReactJS supports the `onSubmit` event by emitting synthetic events for native HTML elements.

For a `<form>` element, you can use the submit event to prevent the default behavior by using `event.preventdefault()`.

You can do it in two easy steps:

1. Define an event handler for your form
2. Use the event handler to prevent form submission

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import data from "./info.json";
function App() {
    const [searchTerm, setSearch] = useState(null);

    const fnHandleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={fnHandleSubmit}>
                <input
                type="text"
                id=""
                placeholder="Search"
                onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
                />
            </form>
            {data
            .filter((data) => {
                if (searchTerm == null) {
                return data;
                } else if (
                data.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
                ) {
                return data;
                }
            })
            .map((data) => (
                <li>{data.name}</li>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

When clicked Enter, it triggers onSubmit(), default action is to refresh.
So to onSubmit() add preventDefault to overcome default behaviour.

Add the following line.

```
<form onSubmit={e => { e.preventDefault(); }}>
//code
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to add `e.preventDefault();`
to your `onSubmit` function to prevent your component from reloading.

However, I'll advise you to use React UI solutions like Ant Design which provides the feature out of the box and also allow you to write your code more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

The `preventDefault()` method cancels the event if it is `cancelable`, meaning that the default action that belongs to the event will not occur.

For example, this can be useful when:

- Clicking on a "Submit" button, prevent it from submitting a form
- Clicking on a link, prevent the link from following the URL

```js
const Test = () => {
  const submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('I am here without refresh the form!')
  }
  return <form onSubmit={submit}>
    <input type = 'text' ></input> 
    </form>
}

ReactDOM.render( <Test/> ,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```